# 3200x1800 display and Excel

Tags: laptop, resolution

I've got a Full HD 15.6 inch laptop that has a 1920 X 1080 resolution. I use it mostly for Visual Studio and the more vertical space you can see the better. And then I also use Excel quite a bit and for large spreadsheets you need horizontal space. Currently, when I open Excel in full screen I can see columns A through AC and rows 1 to 41.

If I get a 3200 X 1800 resolution laptop, will I be able to see more space (for instance all the way to row 73 or so) or is the extra resolution just about displaying a crisper image?

Thanks.

Comment: Hold down control while using the mouse wheel to zoom in and out to display more or less on any display. Works in Excel for the main worksheet and in Visual Studio for the editor along with a lot of other applications. Most also have zoom settings someplace in the UI for the main display area.

Comment: @Brian: I'm not looking to change the zoom on my current display; I'm asking about 3200x1800 resolution screens.

Comment: I think Brian’s point is that when you zoom in, you increase the pixel density of the image and when you zoom out, you decrease it. If you don’t have enough physical pixels, then you get a broken or blurry image, so having a greater number of available pixels means that you with a display that has more pixels, you can display more information at 100% than before without getting a broken image; you can also zoom out further before the image breaks up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. You will see more data on screen because the screen will be 1280 pixels wider, regardless if housed in a similar size frame. However if the screen IS of a similar size, the data will be equivently smaller. It's all about ratios. They're fun!